# Saving log information Update operation get "objectcontext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to save only the modified fields on log table ( for that I compare two modelsnew and old) but appear this exception "objectcontext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations"  on a fields that have relationship with other table. How can I skip this or could you give me any suggestion?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo cur in newmodel.GetType().GetProperties()){
    try
    {
    var original = model.GetType().GetProperty(cur.Name).GetValue(model, null);
    var current = newmodel.GetType().GetProperty(cur.Name).GetValue(newmodel, null);
    if (original != null && !original.Equals(current))
      {
      parameters += cur.Name + " : " + original + "Change to" + current + "<br>";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform this while the connection is open, so when you initialize DBContext, you need to keep it open and do your operations within `using` statemtns:

```
using (var context = new DBContext()) 
{     
    // Perform data access using the context 
}
```